# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400 on https

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io

I am getting below error when I installed the ssl certificate for my domain. So I have changed websocket URL begin with ws:// to wss:// but I am getting this error.
I am using Amazon Linux, docker with jenkins. Backend is in Node JS. Front is Angular JS (1).
Anyone can help us on that?

[image]